# Installation and setup issue in YII2 framework

Tags: yii2-basic-app

I am trying to install yii2 basic application and deployed it in weblogic wls10.3.6 server but i am getting  the following error i can see in app.log

> 2017-09-04 11:34:06
>   [192.168.1.5][-][-][warning][yii\log\Dispatcher::dispatch] Unable to
>   send log via yii\debug\LogTarget: Exception 'Exception' with message
>   ''yii\web\session_status' is an unknown function.'
>
> in Env.java:6904
>
> Stack trace:

As a result web page is coming blank.
Kindly help me in setting up the yii2 base application in wls server.what parameters do i need to set up and pointer or instructure will reply help me.
I have followed the steps given in installation doc through yii framework site.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

To deploy PHP application on Weblogic , you need to use any PHP java bridge.

1.PHP Java Bridge

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

2. Quercus

http://quercus.caucho.com/quercus-3.1/index.xtp

Answer (score 0):

steps to run the Yii project in weblogic with PHP 5.6 and latest Quercus

1. Download and Install WAMP or PHP 5.6 independently and add the PHP installed location in PATH environmental variables in windows, so php will work in command prompt
2. Open command prompt and navigate to your project folder then Run the following command  to create Yii application using PHP 5.6 
   yiic webapp path/to/directory

reference : 
http://www.larryullman.com/2009/10/31/getting-started-with-the-yii-framework/

3. Copying the existing Yii project files to your new project folder as per folder structure.
4. Download Quercus 4.0.38 war file from http://quercus.caucho.com/
5. Unzip the Quercus war
6. Move the META-INF , WEB-INF folders and web.xml file from Quercus to your project root folder location
7. Download and install latest Java run time environment (Java JDK 1.8)
8. Create new domain in Weblogic server with referencing Java JDK 1.8
9. Deploy the application in Weblogic under newly created domain using weblogic console